# I am using rnn_decoder and getting error that inputs are not iterable

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, encoder-decoder

I am getting this error and not able to fix it:

> ~.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py 
>     in **iter**(self)
>         394     if context.in_graph_mode():
>         395       raise TypeError(
>      396           "`Tensor` objects are not iterable when eager execution is 
>     not "
>         397           "enabled. To iterate over this tensor use `tf.map_fn`.")
>         398     shape = self._shape_tuple()
>
> TypeError: `Tensor` objects are not iterable when eager execution is not 
>     enabled. To iterate over this tensor use `tf.map_fn`

My code is:

```
START = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,1, img_size, img_size, 
num_filters1], name='START')
decoder_inputs = tf.map_fn(lambda x: x, START)
decoder_1_outputs_state = tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.rnn_decoder(
    decoder_inputs, encoder_1_final_state, decoder_1_rnn_cell, loop_fn)
```

Comment: Could you add some code so we can reproduce the error?

Comment: At a first glance, I would suggest to replace `decoder_inputs` by a list of `Tensor`s.

Comment: @npf could you give an example of what you mean?